# Firebase , second push() in same method does not work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app , there is an activity which upon clicking the save button, 2 sets of data in 2 different places should be made by `push()`, Since in both places an unique id is needed.

I have followed the sample code in the Firebase guide and added the second push

```
 String userId = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid().toString();
 DatabaseReference reference =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
 DatabaseReference firstDatabaseRef = reference.child("first");
 DatabaseReference secondDatabaseRef = reference.child("second").child(userId);



 String key = firstDatabaseRef.child(userId).push().getKey();
 First first = new First(firstAmount,key,firstName);
 Map<String, Object> firstValues = first.toMap();


 String keySecond = secondDatabaseRef.child(key).push().getKey();
 Second second = new Second(secondName,secondAmount,keySecond,key);
 Map<String, Object> secondValue = second.toMap();

 Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
 childUpdates.put("/first/" + userId + "/" + key, firstValues);
 childUpdates.put("/second/"  + userId + "/" + key + "/" + keySecond, secondValue);
 reference.updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

The result that i got for `first` was exactly as i expected but for `second` , instead of creating `second/<userId>/<key>/<keySecond>/children`, i get this :

```
 "second" : {
    //userId
    "5TQLPlGf4mbcBRKesQwR30fH1L22" : {
      //key
      "-KL1030IywlNpkTGC7mU" : {
        "secondAmount" : "147",
        "Key" : "-KL1030IywlNpkTGC7mU",
        "secondName" : "secondName",
        "keySecond" : "-KL1030PZlHqD_asSR_8",
      }
    }
 }
```

Instead of having the final children in another unique id, which by the way is recorded in the `keySecond`, they are all added directly to the key.
This cannot be accepted since every `key` must have many `keySecond`.
I hope that i explained my problem correctly.
Please tell me what am i doing wrong.
How should i modify my code or should i reconsider my data structure completely ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a puzzle.  I copy/pasted the code you posted and created stubs for `First` and `Second`.  Running with Firebase 9.0.2 produced the result shown below, which I believe is what you are expecting. Are you running with a different Firebase version?  Is it possible the JSON you posted was produced by a different version of the code you posted?

```
{
  "first" : {
    // userId
    "ypx8RB3eglTBRPeUT7laQVQ1PZQ2" : {
      // key
      "-KL3rXeYrscFQNrVQnHb" : {
        "firstAmount" : "FirstAmount",
        "firstKey" : "-KL3rXeYrscFQNrVQnHb",
        "firstName" : "FirstName"
      }
    }
  },
  "second" : {
    // userId
    "ypx8RB3eglTBRPeUT7laQVQ1PZQ2" : {
      // key
      "-KL3rXeYrscFQNrVQnHb" : {
        // keySecond
        "-KL3rXe_JyY9Vz2U-NES" : {
          "Key" : "-KL3rXeYrscFQNrVQnHb",
          "keySecond" : "-KL3rXe_JyY9Vz2U-NES",
          "secondAmount" : "SecondAmount",
          "secondName" : "SecondName"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Sorry for the typo, i fixed it. I use the same version of Firebase which is 9.0.2 and i even tried the code with multiple users. If you have got the right results with the code, there might be something else which is causing the issue.

Comment: again i have to thank you for your answer , although i still have no idea why i was getting that result, i recreated a similar project with the exact same code and now it is working. I was really a puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

When processing the `updateChildren()`, the Firebase Database loops over the children that you pass and for each key it essentially does a `setValue()` with the value you passed.

That means that if you have children with overlapping keys, the value of one of those keys will be written last. The order of these is undefined.

In your case it's fairly easy to merge the updates together:

```
 String key = firstDatabaseRef.child(userId).push().getKey();
 First first = new First(firstAmount,key,firstName);
 Map<String, Object> firstValues = first.toMap();

 String keySecond = secondDatabaseRef.child(key).push().getKey();
 Second second = new Second(secondName,secondAmount,keySecond,key);
 Map<String, Object> secondValue = trans.toMap();
 firstValues.put(keySecond, secondValue);  // This is the main change

 Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
 childUpdates.put("/first/" + userId + "/" + key, firstValues);
 reference.updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

Comment: I really appreciate your quick response. I did what you suggested but still i get the exact same results.

Comment: @Frank: I think your solution fixes a problem that doesn't exist. The two children of `childUpdates` are rooted at `first` and `second`.  Their values don't overlap, do they?

Comment: Ah, right.... good catch! I completely overlooked that. Back to scanning the hashmaps it is...